# Python Attribute Value

Tags: python, attributes

I have the following Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def f(x):
    f.counter = getattr(f, "counter", 0)
    print("Bfore: ",f.counter)
    f.counter += 1
    print("After: ",f.counter)
    return "pass"


for i in range(5):
    f(i)
```

When I run the above code, I see the following results:

```
('Bfore: ', 0)
('After: ', 1)
('Bfore: ', 1)
('After: ', 2)
('Bfore: ', 2)
('After: ', 3)
('Bfore: ', 3)
('After: ', 4)
('Bfore: ', 4)
('After: ', 5)
```

I was expecting:

```
f.counter = getattr(f, "counter", 0)
```

to be always initialized to zero with each call to:

```
f(i)
```

in my

```
for
```

loop.  But that does not seem to be the case. Why?

Thanks.

Comment: You're using Python 2 but syntax suggests you want to use Python 3. Either install Python 3 (if you're on windows), or on *nix, run `python3`.

Comment: Why did you expect that? Where/when did you think it would be initialized? `f` is always referring to the same function object, if you want to reset it to zero you'll have to do so manually; `for i in range(5): f.counter = 0; f(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

`f.counter = getattr(f, "counter", 0)` will only set it to zero if it doesn't exist. If you want to set it to zero each time it is called, set it directly:

```
f.counter = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`f` is always referring to the same function object.

`f.counter = getattr(f, "counter", 0)` sets the value of `f.counter` to the current value of `f.counter` or 0 if the attribute does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, in python, everything is an object. So, while doing `def f(...)` you just create a new instance of a function. You can convince yourself by typing:

```
def f(foo):
    print foo

type(f)  # return <type 'function'>
```

Here `f` has been instantiated on the first line. So, in you example, you always working on a same `f` instance. At the first call, you add an `counter` attribute to it. At the second and next calls, you're still working with the same instance, so the `counter` attribute is still there.